# All files containing assembly references

Tags: c#

Trying to hunt down a way to fix this error without building a new solution.
I have removed and re-added the Json reference with no luck inside VS.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json (1)' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

It looks like it somehow was referenced twice since it has `(1)` in it.

Comment: why don't you simply hunt down the referenced assemblies in all your projects for newtonsoft and carefully examine the assembly path and then carefully verify that the version of the said assembly is same as the one mentioned in web.config `dependentAssemblies`. And if nothing works, try re-installing the json.net package

Comment: Cant you do a CTRL-F on the whole solution and find every page that uses this reference, and check that the correct assembly is being referenced per call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the file in the bin folder and just deleted it. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, that sort of error tends to happen if the assembly is renamed. The `(1)` looks like it may be the case.

I would try removing the reference (all instances of this particular reference) and either readding the original file, or getting it again from NuGet. If NuGet is not an option, check the filename of the physical file you're referencing, and make sure there's no (1) on the end of that.

Comment: I removed the reference and accepted the Json update from NuGet but still the same issue. That's why I was trying to located the files that would contain this reference so I can fix it by hand.